# How does one find what base current to use in simulating a phototransistor?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, pspice, phototransistor

How does one find what base current to use in simulating a phototransistor?

I wish to use LTspice to simulating a phototransistor (LPT80), so I downloaded the model but I have not found information on the base current to use?

And how do I relate the base current to daylight?

Is there a better way to know than trial and error? eg -1mA does turn it on and 0A does turn it off.

The model (in "OSRAM Phototransistors II.lib") can be found here https://www.osram.com/apps/downloadcenter/os/?path=%2Fos-files%2FElectrical+Simulation%2FIR%2FSilicon+Photodetectors%2FPSpice+Libraries%2F

The datasheet for LPT80A is:https://www.osram.com/ecat/Radial%20Sidelooker%20LPT%2080%20A/com/en/class_pim_web_catalog_103489/global/prd_pim_device_2219650/#tools

[image: My LTspice LPT80 circuit]

Comment: That diagram looks wrong. Shouldn't the current be going _into_ the Base?

Comment: Yes, it is as I'm using negative current. It is just a test circuit. :)

Comment: Please link to THE data sheet and not a lib file

Comment: A link to the datasheet has now been added.

Answer (score 1):

Photodiodes are typically spec'd at 0.5 amp per watt of photon flux.

So work from that concept.

Comment: Interesting, so is that "0.5A" collector emitter current "per watt of photon flux"?

Do you have any reference?

Comment: Photodiodes don't have collector current. (Reference any photodiode datasheet). Since a phototransistor's base region is the photodiode. take that as 0.5A/watt of base current.